# Disable CORS using kubernetes ingress

Tags: kubernetes, cors, nginx-ingress

Is it possible to forcefully disable CORS using kubernetes nginx ingress when the application is allowing CORS?

I have an application that I believe is sending `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true` header.

I tried the following but its not working.

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: 'false'
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: 'false'
```

I thought maybe the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors` is to enable the usage of other CORS related annotations ([the official doc's wording is a bit confusing](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#enable-cors)) so I tried keeping it to `true` but even that didnt work

All the posts and examples I came across were for enabling CORS. Does this work only if the headers are not already set by your application?